# How do you get the underlying SAFEARRAY from a CComSafeArray?

Tags: c++, safearray

I tried the `GetSafeArrayPtr()` method which returns a LPSAFEARRAY* that a typedef defined as:

```
typedef /* [wire_marshal] */ SAFEARRAY *LPSAFEARRAY;
```

I thought I would be able to directly assign this to a SAFEARRAY* variable but the compiler gives this error:

> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'LPSAFEARRAY *' to 'SAFEARRAY
>   *'

I found this strange. What am I doing wrong here?

PS: I am doing this inside a C++/CLI dll (if that is of any relevance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LPSAFEARRAY *` is a pointer to `SAFEARRAY *`, so you need a double pointer, like this:

```
{
    CComSafeArray<VARIANT> vArray;
    SAFEARRAY** pArray;
    pArray = vArray.GetSafeArrayPtr();
}
```

And then you can pass the `SAFEARRAY *` to the function that needs it as an argument by dereferencing the pointer returned from `CComSafeArray`:

```
DummyFunction(*pArray);
```

Comment: But I cannot change the definition of the SAFEARRAY variable. Is there any other way I can get the SAFEARRAY to assign to SAFEARRAY* pArray?

Comment: I did not quite understand what are you trying to achieve. What do you mean by "cannot change the definition" ? If you want to modify the data you can do that already through the `CComSafeArray`, also via the `LPSAFEARRAY*`

Comment: I mean I need to pass the safearray to a method that takes SAFEARRAY* as a parameter. Its an external API so I cannot change it.

Comment: Ok, so going forth from this example, why can't you just dereference the pointer you get from `GetSafeArrayPtr()` and pass it to the method? Like `*pArray`.